# prompt users for input after pressing a button on Kotlin Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, input, mobile

I have an app with multiple buttons, where I want the user to be able to long-press on any of them and be able to change the text inside.

I thought about bringing the user's keyboard up when the long-press in registered, and then storing whatever they type in inside of a `text` variable and then use `btn.setText(text)` to update the button. However, I do not know how to prompt the user for input without having to resort to using a text field, which I would like to avoid as much as possible.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: your question dose not clear can you give some code or image or explain?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a material card view (for better design) and have it look like a regular button but with EditText inside of it. you can enable or disable the edit text with the code.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:elevation="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="THIS IS A BUTTON"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```